# Proof that $\sqrt[n]{a+1}$ and $\sqrt[n]{a-1}$ cannot be both rationals

Tags: number-theory, radicals, irrational-numbers

Let $a \neq 0$ be a natural number. How can be proved that $\sqrt[n]
{a+1}$ and $\sqrt[n]{a-1}$ cannot be both rational numbers?

Comment: Have you tried anything?\

Comment: @DietrichBurde here we have _rational_ $a$, instead of _integer_ $n$ (although without reading I assume the proof still might work).

Comment: $a=5/4{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: +1: Why so many downvotes for a first timer?

Comment: @Wojowu: $ a \in \mathbb{N} $.

Comment: @Transcendental Now, yes, but not at the [time](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1818858/revisions) of Wowoju's comment.

Comment: @MrYouMath I have downvoted because, at the time, the statement to be proven was plain wrong. Now that it's fixed I have retracted my downvote.

Comment: @Wojowu Ah that makes sense :).

Answer (score 0):

I presume $n$ is an integer $> 1$.

If $x = (a+1)^{1/n}$ and $y = (a-1)^{1/n}$ are rational, we have 
$$ x^n - 1 = a = y^n + 1$$
$x$ and $y$ are algebraic integers which are rational, thus they are (ordinary) integers, and 
$$ 2 = x^n - y^n$$
Now $x^n - y^n$ is divisible by $x-y$, so $x-y$ can only be $1$ or $2$.
And then it's easy to prove that the only possibility is $x=1$, $y=-1$, $a=0$, $n$ odd.